# Limit tomcat stdout file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, size, stdout

I have never used Tomcat before, but we have a 3rd party application that is installed on Windows 2003 that uses it.  The STDOUT log file is huge.  I thought about just going in and deleting it figured that was not the best approach - it might break something.  So, how  can someone like me who's not familier with Tomcat "at all" limit that file size.  Can someone provide step by step instructions?

Comment: Are you talking about the `catalina.out` file in TOMCAT_HOME/logs?

Comment: Have you check the documentation? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: You need to fix the webapp to stop producing output on standard output.